# Watch Connectivity: Transfer user info when phone not nearby

Tags: ios, watchos, watchconnectivity

I am trying to transfer data from Apple Watch to iOS. I use `transferUserInfo` to do so. It is very likely that, when I call that method, the phone is not nearby (and therefore not reachable).

As far as I understood the documentation, the user info should be queued and delivered to the phone by Watch Connectivity when the phone becomes reachable again. This does not seem to be true for me, instead my session delegate's `session(didFinish:error:)` gets called with a `Transfer timed out.` error.

This is bad since that means the watch app and iOS app need to be active at the same time in order for iOS to receive the latest info. Is this expected behaviour, and is there any way to fix this?

I know that application context might have the behaviour I need, but the message size for application context is pretty limited, which might be an issue for me if the iOS app is not opened for a while (I am transferring workouts, so they might accumulate on the watch).